# complicated volume integral

Tags: integration, volume, divergence-operator

I suspect that $$\iiint d \tau \,\,\, {\bf r} {\bf \cdot} {\bf c} \,\,\, {\bf J} {\bf \cdot} {\bf d}$$ is equal to $$\iiint d \tau \,\,\, \frac{1}{2} {\bf r} \times {\bf J} \, {\bf \cdot}\, {\bf c} \times {\bf d}$$
where ${\bf c}, {\bf d}$ are constant vectors and ${\bf J}$ is such that any surface integrals over all space involving ${\bf J}$ vanish.

I'm having a very difficult time showing this result and any help, hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "any surface integrals involving $\mathbf{J}$ vanish"?

Comment: @ConnorHarris Changed to include "any surface integrals over all space", so that any volume integral involving $\nabla \cdot ( {\bf J} (\,\,other \,\,stuff) )$ can be set  to zero, since this would involve $\iint ({\bf J} (\,\,other \,\,stuff)) \cdot d {\bf a} \equiv 0$

Comment: At first I thought you were crazy, but the bac-cab rule seems to give you a result that is oddly close to what you want. $$(\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{J}) \cdot (\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{d}) = \mathbf{c} \cdot (\mathbf{d} \times (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{J})) = \mathbf{c} \cdot (\mathbf{r} (\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{J}) - \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{r})) = (\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{c})(\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{d}) - (\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{c})(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{d})$$